# fs.write in two txt files using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, fs

brothers i want to write a results in two txt files i tried this but no way :

```js
 var async = require('async');
 var fs = require('fs');
 async.parallel([
    function(callback){
      fs.writeFile('result.txt',"text to write1",callback);
  
    },
    function(callback){
    
   fs.writeFile('result2.txt',"text to write2",callback);
  
    }
],
function(err, results){
    console.log("can'r write");
});
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Are errors reported? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: Please make your question a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [M.C.V E](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make your post answerable.

Answer (score 0):

So I see that you're using the async library here. Keep in mind that per the documentation for fs, the **fs.writeFile(file, data[, options], callback)** function is already asynchronous. If your code isn't working, consider simplifying and eliminating the use of async. Consider the following:

```
fs.writeFile('result.txt',"text to write1",
    function(err)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log("Failed to write file!");
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
fs.writeFile('result2.txt',"text to write2",callback);
    function(err)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log("Failed to write file!");
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```